# Why Xamarin android Designer not display in visual studio 2012 when opening *.axml file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I'm creating an Android application with Visual Studio 2012 and Xamarin but when I try to open any *.axml file ( that contain android layout and design and other element ) It suppose to display an wysiwyg visual IDE so I edit things easylly but it could not load wysiwyg and give me error that “ the operation could not be completed. invalid pointer “
I use gtk sharp 2.12.21 , mono-android 4.6.06000 , JDK 6, android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86, XamarinStudio 4.0.8
I also include image see below

[image]

Can anyone tell how to solve this problem

Comment: What version of android sdk are you using? In xamarin.android 4.6.6 was just added the support of 22 (not 22.6 that is the last one now as I know, but the first release of 22 version)

Comment: Any of the answers fix your problem? Have you tested them?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure what file you are opening that is included in project.

so if if is showing not highlighted then right click on file> Include in project
it will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that worked for me.

Update the android **sdk tools to 24.1.2** and make sure you are have  skd platform-tools updated.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurred to me as well, because I did something that I obviously shouldn't have done: I uninstalled some packages from the Android SDK Manager that seemed obsolete to me, but were required for Xamarin.

In case you see the same error, try uninstalling Xamarin and re-installing it. During that process, the installer verifies that all required packages are installed.